# Weight-of-Evidence Functions (Woe.binning vs. Woebin) as Workaround for Non-Linearity Log-Odds in Logistic Regression?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic

I have seen weight-of-evidence cited as a way to address non-linearity in LR models. Has anyone seen/heard of the same? The function I am particularly using is woe.binning in R for this.

The linearity log-odds is failing, so I am using woe.binning (R function) for it. But, I am unclear whether "woebin" from library scorecard would be more appropriate? The logic behind both of these packages is still a bit unclear (I know conceptually what they are doing, but in terms of manually replicating it or explaining the logic, not sure).

woe.binning --> https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/woeBinning/woeBinning.pdf

Woebin --> https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/scorecard/html/woebin.html

Comment: Search this site for "weight of evidence", but more important, edit your post to tell us more about your concrete logistic regression problem

Comment: I have added a second note to the original post.

Comment: The weight of evidence formula _is_ the log-odds of a categorical level, so not only is it linear in log-odds, the coefficient ought to be 1. That's thrown off by having multiple features, and maybe the binning itself; but I don't know to what extent that can wreck things.